# Can't get result from NSURL

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsurl

I'm trying to read remote txt file, which is located at remote hosting. I have a link, like http://www.link.com/file.txt.

I am using this code:

```
let myURLString = "http://google.com"
guard let myURL = NSURL(string: myURLString) else {
    print("Error: \(myURLString) doesn't seem to be a valid URL")
    return
}

do {
    let myHTMLString = try String(contentsOfURL: myURL)
    print("HTML : \(myHTMLString)")
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

But always getting empty string. File is not empty for sure. 
I'm running my app on iOS simulator in Xcode.
What am I doing wrong?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: what's the error that comes back?

Comment: I tested your code in a playground (with google.com as example) and I get a result. The code works fine it seems. Could you share the txt link? Can you fetch the link in your terminal (e.g. with wget).

Comment: You can use a proxy debugger (e.g. Charles Proxy, etc) to verify that your http request is being sent and the response contains the expected content.

Comment: but I'm getting error even when I' trying to get result from google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use stringWithContentsOfURL and friends to retrieve data from a remote server.  That's a synchronous API that was designed solely for use with local files.  It isn't even guaranteed to work right for network requests on background threads, much less in your main thread.

The right way to retrieve data from remote URLs is with NSURLSession.  I'm not a Swift programmer, so I'm not going to attempt a Swift snippet, but the Objective-C equivalent is:

```
NSURL *url = ...
NSURLSessionDataTask *task =
    [NSURLSession sharedSession dataTaskWithURL:url
                              completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                                  NSURLResponse *response,
                                                  NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // Handle client-side errors here
        } else if (((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).statusCode != 200) {
            // Handle server-side errors here
        } else {
            NSString *stock = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            // Do something with data here.
        }
    }];
[task resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't test the code, but this should lead you on the right direction.

```
var statsRequest: String = "http://www.link.com/file.txt"
var statsRequestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: statsRequest)!
var error: NSError? = nil
var stockNews: String = try! String.stringWithContentsOfURL(statsRequestURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

If the text file has a different encoding you can just use NSASCIIStringEncoding and then parse the html file.